# How to return an error code from a process that runs in another cmd window (windows)

Tags: windows, cmd

I'm running a script from the cmd prompt. This script opens another cmd prompt and runs another batch file there. I want to wait for the error code and then send it back to the original cmd window. Is there a nice way to do this without writing the error code to a file?

Thanks,
Li

Comment: Not sure, but this could help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4336270/how-to-pass-values-from-child-process-to-parent-cmd-exe-shell

Comment: Thanks, this should work, but I'm actually openning a new command window.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I inderstand you correctly, you want [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4864670/how-to-exit-a-cmd-file-and-the-shell-at-the-same-time/4876381#4876381). It solves the problem of returning error level to the calling script from the script that was run in a separate `cmd` session.